# How to change parentId property on Extjs NodeInterface

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, extjs4

I creating simple tree with rest service on *Extjs 4.1*.
How can I change parentId property name from `Ext.data.NodeInterface`?

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define('Buildlife.model.Folder', { 
    extend:'Ext.data.Model', idProperty:'id',  
    fields:[
        {name:'id', type:'auto',defaultValue:null},
        {name:'name', type:'auto'},  
        {name:'files',type:'auto',convert:function(val,rec){
            for(var i in val){
                var each = val[i];
                Ext.apply(each,{
                    name: each.fileName,
                    leaf:true,
                    iconCls:'x-event-icon'
                });
                rec.appendChild(rec.createNode(each));
            } 
            return val;
        },defaultValue:null}
    ], 
    proxy:{
        type:'rest', 
        url:GlobalConf.contextPath+'/rest/folder', 
        reader:{type:'json', root:'children', successProperty:'success'}, 
        writer:{type:'json', root:'children', writeAllFields:false}, 
        listeners:{exception:GlobalConf.storeExceptionHandler}
    }
});
```

When I add child node, it send parent node as a parentId.

```
{
    "children": {
        "name": "test",
        "parentId": "4fc742f344aeac0cc87e6afa",
        "leaf ": false
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change it to customProperty such as:

```
{
    "children": {
        "name": "test",
        "customProperty": "4fc742f344aeac0cc87e6afa",
        "leaf ": false
        //etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. ParentId is part of the NodeInterface class which every tree node subclasses. You would have to override the 'decorate' static method listed here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/NodeInterface.html#Ext-data-NodeInterface
Also there is an updateInfo method that gets called after a node move that will try to set parentId property - so that must be changed too.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. I didn't noticed that static method. Thank you so much =D